# performance of reciprocal calculation in c++

Tags: c++, performance, math, inverse

Is there any way how to improve performance of calculation [image: \frac{1}{1%2Ba*b}] without loosing precision? Currently I'm simply doing:

```
1 / (1 + a * b)
```

Where **a** and **b** are double. Value of **a** is constant. I need to do millions of such calculations.

Comment: How much precision do you need?

Comment: How much performance do you need? Does `a` and `b` follow some predictable pattern for this millions of calculations?

Comment: You need to provide some additional context.  The equation itself looks to be pretty well optimized as is, but it's unclear how you're using it.  Is it in a loop? Is it iterating over values in an array? Is it a standalone method, and if so, how is it declared? What optimization settings are you using on your build?  These, and a number of other issues are likely to impact performance.

Comment: millions is trivial. billions of a computation that small shouldn't be worth optimizing.  So what information did you leave out that makes this worth optimizing?

Comment: I need maximum possible precision(at least not worst when calculation is done standard way). Value of a is always constant and equal for example: 0.1721271. Value of b is unpredictable.

Comment: pre computing `ra=1/a` so you can use `ra/(ra+b)` should be a trivial improvement in speed without loss of precision.  But I'd still prefer a wider view to understand what you're actually trying to optimize.

Comment: @JSF are you sure that does not lose precision? I'd like to see proof.

Comment: This calculation is not in the loop. I have a function and inside this function I have some formula and I need to multiply this formula by 1 / (1 + a * b). I'm using standard compiler options like -O3 -DNDEBUG.

Comment: You seem to be explaining why you **DON'T** have reason to optimize this.  You just implied you do `m=1/(1+a*b)` less often than `f*m` so improving `1/(1+a*b)` won't make an interesting difference.

Comment: Did you profile?  Is this line the bottleneck?  Usually loops are causes of bottlenecks, not individual statements.   Although division is well known for eating up execution time.

Comment: Have you considered fixed point arithmetic?  Fixed point can be more accurate than floating point.

Comment: @JSF I'm not calculating m less often then f*m. I'm always doing f*m and I'm doing this millions time. So any improvement of calculation of m is beneficial.

Comment: @Thomas I have not tried to profile as there is no reason for this. Calculation of m is no the slowest part but this is just one place where I try to improve. Also I have not tried fixed point arithmetic.

Comment: If you are computing that reciprocal once per use, why do you have that excess multiply?? Why not `f/(1+a*b)` ?  Also, once again, why are you talking about optimizing something done "millions" of times?? Millions is trivial.

Comment: Thanks of your answers. I'll try to remove one multiplication and I'll try to pre compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's separate when `a == 0`, `a != 0`,

- if `a == 0`, then answer is `1` (crystal clear)
- if `a ==!0`, let `c = 1/a`

(`c` is also constant) then entire expression becomes

```
    c / (b + c)
```

This will save one of multiplication calculation.

Comment: You need to use the associative and the distributive law to simplify the expression. Unfortunately, floating point math is neither distributive, nor associative. Assuming that it is, can result in loss of precision. I'd like to see proof that no precision is lost.

Comment: Are you wondering about "loss" of accuracy or simply change in accuracy?  Certainly, that change can change the result.  Whether the changed result is more or less accurate is a more complicated question.  I don't see the reason to believe it would tend to be less accurate (unless you are in an old architecture in which intermediate values of `double` are kept in 80-bit).

Comment: I like the check for `a==0`.  Likewise, a check should be made for `b==0`.  Comparisons are faster than division.  However, since `a` and `b` are floating point, the comparison for zero is difficult.  One would have to compare against an *epsilon* value instead of exact equivalence to zero.

Comment: In the original post, a is constant, so that getting reciprocal is one time job.

Comment: In some programming environments (e.g. CUDA on NVIDIA GPUs), a reciprocal calculation may be significantly faster than a full division, so the proposed transformation may speed up the code or make it slower. Unfortunately the asker of the question hasn't given enough context to assess that risk.

Comment: Arithmetic in the ordinary program is not computed in GPU as far as I know, and there is no separated CPU instruction to get reciprocal. There might be a better way, but what I am going to say is my expression reduces one multiplication and it will result in faster processing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to compute given expression iteratively (millions of times). As far as you have iterative process - you can consider doing it **in parallel**. In given case I'd think about SIMD (vector) parallelism.

Modern x86 processors have various SIMD parallel variants of instructions for "packed" (i.e. SIMD parallel) *divisions* and "packed" (SIMD parallel) *reciprocals* with different accuracy.

It means that **if** you are capable to "vectorize" your iterative algorithm (using modern Compilers, pragmas like OpenMP4.x, etc) and run resulting application on modern x86 hardware with AVX support (Sandy Bridge or later, i.e. released after 2011), then quite likely Compiler will use efficient and fast vector **parallel** divisions or reciprocals (or newton-rhapson scheme) depending on floating point accuracy compilation options chosen by you. On some platforms Packed (parallel) Division is mostly as fast as Scalar (sequential) Division, while processing **4-16 more elements at a time**. On its turn reciprocals are much faster than Divisions .

Here is a list of packed AVX and AVX512  division/reciprocal instructions to give you some idea ( *RCP stands for Reciprocal. PS stands for parallel single precision floating point, PD stands for parallel double-precision FP, DIV stands for Division. AVX - is what your CPU support starting from ~2011. AVX-512 is what some of "CPUs" will support starting from ~2nd half of 2016*)

- **ISA  | Instruction | Accuracy**
- AVX  | VRCPS (no DP) | 2^-12
- AVX, AVX2 |  VDIVPD/PS
- AVX-512F | VRCP14PD/PS | 2^ -14
- AVX-512F | VDIVPD/PS   |  53 bit??
- AVX-512ER| VRCP28PD/PS | 2^ -28?